# solution of differential equation

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I have the following code that gives you a phase portrait of a 2d system and I can't understand what means the 3rd and 4th line (sol1 and sol2).

```
sys = {x'[t] == 3 x[t], y'[t] == -y[t]};

ss = DSolve[sys, {x[t], y[t]}, t];

sol1 = ss[[1, 1, 2]];

sol2 = ss[[1, 2, 2]];

toplot = Flatten[
  Table[{sol1, sol2} /. {C[1] -> i, C[2] -> j}, 
    {i, -0.5, 0.5, 0.25}, {j, -0.5, 0.5, 0.25}], 1]

graphs = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[toplot], {t, -3, 3}]
```

I searched the documentation but I couldn't figure it out. Thank you.

@J.M. @belisarius I try to extend it in non linear eqiations.
I tried another example with a non linear diff eq. What I wanted to find was the phase space. When I put μ>0 then it plots a solution, but it does not show the other fixed point that is non stable. For everything else μ it does not do anything.

`sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == μ - x[t]^2, y'[t] == -y[t], x[0] == x0, 
   y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]`

`toplot = Table[{x@t, y@t} /. sol, {x0, -.5, 
    2, .25}, {y0, -.5, .5, .25}];`

`ParametricPlot[Evaluate[toplot], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]`

I now the dynamics of the above, I do not want you to explain that to me. I want your help because I am trying to learn mathematica.

Comment: It's for extracting the (approximate) solutions, though I think it's a bit cumbersome, and I prefer using `{sol1, sol2} = {x, y} /. First[ss];`

Comment: @J.M. `{x@t, y@t} /. First[ss]` in this case

Comment: thank you very much! can you explain me or send me any link that explains what `x@t` means?

Comment: @bel, blah, I'm too used to not including the arguments for the functions... 2island, the double bracket syntax is shorthand for `Part[]`. You will want to look this up in the docs. Additionally, `x[t]`, `x @ t`, and `t // x` all mean the same thing; that is, applying the function `x` to the argument `t`.

Comment: Where did you see this code, BTW? It's quite weird that the one who wrote it does know about replacement rules, given the fifth line, but seems to forget about it in extracting functions from the output of `DSolve[]`.

Comment: For future reference on how to figure these things out: search the docs for `[[` and it'll take you to `Part` which explains the syntax used in the line `sol1 = ...`.  The meaning of `@` is a bit more difficult to discover.  Searching for it takes you to `Prefix`, but [here's a more relevant doc page.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html)

Comment: Ok! Thank you for your help. @J.M. this was from supplementary notes given by a tutor in my master in non linear dynamics lesson. The notes were from another student.

Comment: Your new question should be split off into a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ss = DSolve[{x'[t] == 3 x[t], y'[t] == -y[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, t];
toplot = Table[{x@t, y@t} /. ss, {x0, -0.5, 0.5, 0.25}, {y0, -0.5, 0.5, 0.25}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[toplot], {t, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it right to use the NDSolve (when u want to treat with a non linear diff eq) and as initial cond put variables as above?
`Plot[r (1 - r^2), {r, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {r, r'}]
ssa = NDSolve[{r'[t] == r[t] (1 - r[t]^2), u'[t] == 1, r[0] == r0, 
   u[0] == u0}, {r[t], u[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]
toplot = Table[{r@t Cos[u@t], r@t Sin[u@t]} /. ssa, {r0, -.5, .5, 
    0.25}, {u0, -.5, .5, 0.25}];`
ParametricPlot[toplot, {t, 0, 100}] The solution seems right but it opens a message that says that initial cond r0 is not a number or rectangular array of numbers.

Comment: @2island You must plug in numbers in `NDSolve[]`, not symbolic constants