# Non linear equation phase space

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

As a supplementary to my question [solution of differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23881/solution-of-differential-equation?noredirect=1#comment74481_23881) I post a new question of how is it possible to make a Table that has elements the solutions of a non linear differential equation, so that to plot them. In a linear system you can do the following:

```
ss = DSolve[{x'[t] == 3 x[t], y'[t] == -y[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, t];
toplot = Table[{x@t, y@t} /. ss, {x0, -0.5, 0.5, 0.25}, {y0, -0.5, 0.5, 0.25}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[toplot], {t, -1, 1}]
```

as @belisarius proposed.

If I have to use `NDSolve` can I use variables as above in initial conditions?
I first tried the following example.

```
Plot[r (1 - r^2), {r, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {r, r'}] 
ssa = NDSolve[{r'[t] == r[t] (1 - r[t]^2), u'[t] == 1, r[0] == r0, 
              u[0] == u0}, {r[t], u[t]}, {t, 0, 100}] 
toplot = Table[{r@t Cos[u@t], r@t Sin[u@t]} /. ssa, {r0, -.5, .5, 0.25}, 
                                                    {u0, -.5, .5, 0.25}]; 
 ParametricPlot[toplot, {t, 0, 100}]
```

The solution is what I expected, but it opened a message that said  that initial condition r0 is not a number or rectangular array of numbers.

I then tried another example, it opened the same message but the solution was nearly what I wanted for some values of μ. For μ>0 the solution was OK except that it wasn't shown the second fixed point. For μ<=0 I didn't get any solution.

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == μ - x[t]^2, y'[t] == -y[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, 
             {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]

toplot = Table[{x@t, y@t} /. sol, {x0, -.5, 2, .25}, {y0, -.5, .5, .25}];`

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[toplot], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

**if you copy-paste the code remember to manually treat μ**

The expected plots are shown bellow:

[image: 2d saddle node bifurcation]

Comment: `NDSolve` cannot numerically integrate the system of equations since at this point `r0` and `u0` don't have numerical values. You have to wrap `Table[..., {r0, ...}, {u0, ...}]` around `NDSolve` instead of the plot curves!

Comment: Ok! I suppose that u propose me something like this: `a = Table[
   sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1 - x[t]^2, y'[t] == -y[t], x[0] == x0, 
      y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 100}], {x0, -.5, 
    5}, {y0, -.5, .5}];` After that how can I plot this table that has elements the solutions of an equation? Sorry about my question it might be elementary but now I am really confused.

Comment: You might also be interested in the ``EquationTrekker` `` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you call `NDSolve` while you haven't specified numerical values. Later, in your `Table` they are put in. In your second example you never say which value $\mu$ should get.

An easy way to fix this, is to make a function call out of your `NDSolve`. In this way it gets only evaluated when you put values in.

```
sol = Function[{x0, y0, mu}, 
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == mu - x[t]^2, y'[t] == -y[t], x[0] == x0, 
    y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]]

toplot = Table[{x@t, y@t} /. sol[x0, y0, .5], {x0, -.5, 
    2, .25}, {y0, -.5, .5, .25}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[toplot], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

To interpret the output is of course your job.

[image]

Comment: As I understand u call the `NDSolve` with `sol[x0,y0,.5]` where `.5` is the value of mu (or μ). Again it doesn't work for values less than `.2`, I can't make plots as I posted in my question. I want μ to take values <0, =0 and >0. I know what the output should be like and what does it mean. Is there any way to make the plots as I posted above? I can't find where is the problem, the methodology seems to be right.

Comment: I tried another equation and it work exaclty as I a expected! Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @2island That it doesn't work with mu less than .2 is a problem of the equation and/or the numerical method used by NDSolve. You have to check yourself why it doesn't work.